# uart problem with linux and user written operating system

Tags: operating-system, linux-device-driver, microkernel

statement: i have tried almost all the options for getting to work, trying to send data thru UART from a intel pentium 2 system using a device driver in polled io mode written by me, its very simple the code can be seen in http://pastebin.com/8snzeaXu
also the linux code for sending data http://pastebin.com/YRszQqRv
baud rate and properties like 8-N-1 is set on both the sides ... if u want details regarding serial uart registers use http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/serial-uart.html#LSR
issue: i miss some data in the transmission

Answer (score 0):

Missing data usually means that data is overwritten when sending. Instead of sleeping some usecs between sending bytes, can't you query the status register, like check the LSR for THR empty? Maybe you add flow control like xon/xoff, too.

Comment: To get over the process dispatching and timing over head i wrote a stand alone program to handle uart alone for now, still i have the same issue.
I have the code base on git
for operating system for learning (nanos_src)
for sending (download_file_uart) and receiving (eksw094_s).
do have a look at it. 
https://github.com/bicepjai/nanos